# Programmatically created button Not Working click event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What is wrong in my steps?

```
Do While dread1.Read()
    way = dread1.Item(0).ToString
    sb.Append("<tr ><td>" & dread1.Item(2) & "</td>" + "<td>" & dread1.Item(5) & "</td>" + 
       "<td>" & dread1.Item(0) & "</td>" + 
       "<td><asp:LinkButton runat='server' id='waybutton' class='btn btn-success' on='waybill_Click' />" & dread1.Item(6) & "</td>" + 
       "<td>" & dread1.Item(7) & "</td>" + "<td>" & dread1.Item(8) & "</td>" +
       "<td>" & dread1.Item(9) & "</td>" + "<td>" & dread1.Item(10) & "</td>" + 
       "<td>" & dread1.Item(11) & "</td>" + "<td>" & dread1.Item(12) & "</td>" +  
       "<td>" & dread1.Item(14) & "</td>" + "</tr>")

    l.Text = sb.ToString
    tr1.Controls.Add(l)
Loop

Protected Sub waybill_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Response.Redirect("")
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is there an error message or a way you can add some diagnostic code to try and track down where the problem is. Did you bind the event properly? (I can't see in the code if you did or didn't)

Comment: Button displayed correctly but if clicked nothing

Answer (score 0):

As your codes shows in this line:
`<asp:LinkButton runat='server' id='waybutton' class='btn btn-success' on='waybill_Click'`/>
you want to add ASP.NET dynamic control by a string content and render it, this is not possible in ASP.NET to add some ASP.Net controls to page as HTML string like what you have done, but you can add HTML elements as string so instead of that this is easy to add HTML `button` element as `<button onclick="clientFunction()">Click Me</button>` to the page because HTML can render that string, in the other side it is not possible to execute back-end method directly with an HTML element like firing `waybill_Click` by HTML `button` (it is possible with some tips and tricks).

anyway if you want to add ASP.Net dynamic control and add events for them take a look at [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317794/how-to-dynamically-create-controls-in-asp-net-by-using-visual-c-net) or google `ASP.Net dynamic control`.

**UPDATE:**

```
sb.Append("<tr ><td>" & dread1.Item(2) & "</td>" + "<td>" & dread1.Item(5) & "</td>" + 
       "<td>" & dread1.Item(0) & "</td>" + 
       "<td><a id='waybutton' class='btn btn-success' href="redirectPage.aspx">Link Title</a>" & dread1.Item(6) & "</td>" + 
       "<td>" & dread1.Item(7) & "</td>" + "<td>" & dread1.Item(8) & "</td>" +
       "<td>" & dread1.Item(9) & "</td>" + "<td>" & dread1.Item(10) & "</td>" + 
       "<td>" & dread1.Item(11) & "</td>" + "<td>" & dread1.Item(12) & "</td>" +  
       "<td>" & dread1.Item(14) & "</td>" + "</tr>")
```

but if you need add dynamic `asp:LinkButton` you need to have a ASP.NET holder control like `Panel` or `Form` and then add to it like:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    LinkButton lnkRedirect = new LinkButton();
    lnkRedirect.ID = "lnkRedirect1";
    lnkRedirect.Text = "Redirect";
    lnkRedirect.Click+=new EventHandler(lnkRedirect_Click);
    form1.Controls.Add(lnkRedirect);
 }
 protected void lnkRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Response.Redirect("");
 }
```

this is just a sample ASP.Net C# code, from what you have designed lie a HTML table if you want to add ASP.Net control to that table it is not possible.
you should work pure with either of them, pure ASP.Net or  pure HTML for dynamic purpose.

[at the end this link may help you.](https://www.encodedna.com/2014/07/programmatically-add-linkbutton-to-gridview-aspdotnet.htm)

Comment: I have  already create html table in my asp.net page. I need to add rows programatically and need add button to cell if button clicked need to redirect to another page with session data. it's doesn't matter java script  to.....

Comment: So why you want redirect user to another page by ASP.Net button ? instead of that use `a` if there is no need to execute some beck-end  code.

Comment: I am planing at page load display some massages using session data(session step not include my code yet)